Why does my calculation for transmission line reflection and transmission at a load have infinite solutions?
Take a transmission line with some characteristic impedance and insert a load somewhere along the line. What are the transmitted and reflected signals, given an sinusoidal input. Physically this should have a solution, however mathematically it feels undefined. I can solve it and get infinite solutions. I can constrain the solutions using an intuitive guess, but I'm not sure that's correct. Is the problem undefined? And if so, what happens if this was done in the lab?
Schematic and conventions

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For the rest of this post I'll use these shortened subscripts:

in = input wave
r = reflected wave
t = transmitted wave

I'll also use v of the top line referenced to the bottom line in the schematic.
My convention for current direction will be as shown in the schematic.
[sanity check] If there was no output transmission line
This would be straightforward. Here's the standard solution:

Total Voltage and Current at the Load:

$$
V_{\text{total}} = V_i + V_r \quad \text{and} \quad I_{\text{total}} = \frac{V_i}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_r}{Z_{\text{char}}}
$$

Ohm's Law at the Load:
$$
V_{\text{total}} = Z_{\text{load}} \cdot I_{\text{total}}
$$

Substitute and Simplify:
$$
V_i + V_r = Z_{\text{load}} \left( \frac{V_i}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_r}{Z_{\text{char}}} \right)
$$


This already has the correct number of variables to be well defined. Vr can be solved in terms of Vi.
$$
V_r = V_i \frac{Z_{\text{load}} - Z_{\text{char}}}{Z_{\text{load}} + Z_{\text{char}}} \tag{1}
$$
This is the standard reflection coefficient formula.
[real deal] Including the output transmission line
Now it seems undefined, if we repeat the same analysis:

Total Voltage and Current at the Load:

$$
V_{\text{total}} = V_i + V_r  + V_t\quad \text{and} \quad I_{\text{total}} = \frac{V_i}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_r}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_t}{Z_{\text{char}}}
$$

Ohm's Law at the Load:
$$
V_{\text{total}} = Z_{\text{load}} \cdot I_{\text{total}}
$$

Substitute and Simplify:
$$
V_i + V_r +V_t= Z_{\text{load}} \left( \frac{V_i}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_r}{Z_{\text{char}}} - \frac{V_r}{Z_{\text{char}}} \right)
$$


This has too many variables to be well defined. Given Vi, vr could be anything, as long as the correct vt is chosen.
Alternative approach:
There's an alternative approach with a definite answer. Simply apply the reflection formula (1), but replace Z_load with Z_load parallel Z_char. This would give a single answer to the reflected signal.
Question
I'm assuming that the alternative approach gives the physically correct answer.
Why then does the original approach fail? And how can it be remedied?
Update 1
Conservation of energy might be the reason, because otherwise a transmission line with nothing in the middle could spontaneously generate a wave moving outward in both directions. What's not obvious to me is why the alternative method doesn't need this constraint.


$$V_{\text{total}} = V_i + V_r  + V_t$$

This is not correct. Both \$V_i+V_r\$ and \$V_t\$ are measured from the top terminal of the load to the reference terminal. They are two names for the same potential. They don't add together.
The simple way to solve this problem is to recognize that since the "output" transmission line is infinite in length, it behaves just like a resistor of value \$Z_0\$ placed in parallel with the load impedance. You can then use the parallel combination rule to get a new "equivalent load" and calculate the reflection just as you did in the first part of your post.


Why does my calculation for transmission line reflection and transmission at a load have infinite solutions?

It does not have.
You must calculate two coefficients.
The one is the "reflective" coefficient. The other is the "transmitted" coefficient.
The "reflected" coefficient (voltage) is calculated with LOAD = ZL paralleled with Zc2, the right impedance line.
The "transmission" coefficient is calculated as Vin+Vr= Vt.
As Vr = Vin * Kr ... Vt/Vin = \$ Kt = (1 + Kr) = 2* Zr /(Zc+Zr) \$ ... Kr is "reflective" coefficient.
